# Pythonista URL Scraper on iOS

Tags: iphone, xpath, web-scraping, apple-watch, pythonista

I’ve been attempting to compile a script to give me table data from a few xpaths from https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ to display info from just 4 of the hundreds of datasets.

The issue I’ve run into after playing around with various scripts for hours and hours and doing web searches is that pythonista iOS won’t allow me to utilize pandas, beautiful soup, pyto, or a host of other parsers.

I’m admittedly a noob but it seems like using the basic installed libraries for python 2.7 or 3.2 should be able to simply display Xpath data with a few lines of code with which I will eventually migrate some premade code in iOS shortcuts app to make it a widget for my Apple Watch and/or iPhone.

All this to say... has anyone had success scraping using iOS Pythonista app?   If so, any pointers for an angle of attack??

Answer (score 0):

Pythonista is limited by the fact that you must use [pure python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976946/what-is-pure-python) libraries. This is no fault of the developer and is a restriction set by Apple. I recommend installing [StaSh](https://github.com/ywangd/stash) and finding a pure python scraping library that you can install through pip. A quick google search brought up [this one](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapely) which you might find useful.

Comment: Thank you.  That’s very interesting.   I will take that approach!

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2020, Pythonista has the requests and bs4 modules built in.

Comment: a link to the release notes would be nice